# Finding the lowest value in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, min

I was attempting to take user input in the form of city and temperature and then save it to a dictionary. After that it was supposed to print out what the lowest temperature was and what city it was. I was attempting do this iteratively without the min function though my program never reaches the print message. Why and how could I fix this? Thank you.

Edit: I'm aware that I could use the min function to make this easier but this is a practice exercise and I'm supposed to find the minimum through iteration. Also if temporarily speaking I'm ignoring if 2 or more cities have the lowest temperature.

```
def main():
city = {}
lowest = 0
while True:
    user = input("Enter city followed by temperature: ")
    if user == "stop":
        print(city)
        for value in city.values():
            if int(value) < lowest:
                lowest = int(value)

        for key in city:
            if city[key] == lowest:
                print("The coldest city is,", city[key])
        break

    name, temperature = user.split()
    city[name] = temperature

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you initialize `lowest` to `0`. If all your cities have positive temperatures, `lowest` will never change when you compute the min, and no city will ever satisfy the `if city[key] == lowest:` test.

A way to fix this is to initialize `lowest` to one of the temperatures of the cities. For example you could add:

```
lowest = temperature
```

below

```
if user == "stop":
```

to initialize `lowest` to the last temperature input by the user.

Finally one last problem in your code is in the `if city[key] == lowest` test: the way you construct your dictionary, `city[key]` is a string whereas `lowest` is an integer and these will never be equal. I suggest you convert the temperatures to integers when you construct the dictionary, so that you don't have to deal with the conversion later on. The overall corrected code looks like this:

```
def main():
    city = {}
    while True:
        user = input("Enter city followed by temperature: ")
        if user == "stop":
            print(city)
            lowest = temperature
            for value in city.values():
                if value < lowest:
                    lowest = value

            for key in city:
                if city[key] == lowest:
                    print("The coldest city is,", city)
            break

        name, temperature = user.split()
        temperature = int(temperature)
        city[name] = temperature

main()
```

Comment: I was told to do it without that function actually. It's a practice exercise.

Comment: This can only give a single result. Perhaps 2 or more cities are tied for the lowest temperature

Comment: I'm trying that but unfortunately I'm experiencing the same problem where the program will not print out the statement indicating what is the coldest city and its temperature.

Comment: @user3495234 Yes, it turns out that there was one additional error in your code. Please see the additional explanation and corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to find the lowest is to use `min`

```
lowest = min(city.values())
```

"stop" should `break` out of your loop

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter city followed by temperature: ")
    if user == "stop":
        break
    name, temperature = user.split()
    city[name] = float(temperature)    # convert to float (or perhaps int)


print(city)
lowest = min(city.values())

for key in city:
    if city[key] == lowest:
        print("The coldest city is,", city[key])
```

You may want to consider printing a different message when there is more than one city with the lowest temperature

Comment: I'm not actually allowed to use the min function. I was told to solve for the minimum through iteration.

Comment: ok. The way you are doing it should work (if all the temperatures are greater than zero). You need to convert the temperatures to a numeric type though. Consider a different way of initializing `lowest` to handle temperatures below zero

Comment: Well unfortunately the program won't output "The coldest city is" message so I'm a little bit stuck as to why.

Comment: What _does_ the program do. Are you running it with Python3?

Comment: @gnibbler I disagree, the OP's solution only works when at least one of the temperatures is smaller than zero. Otherwise none of the cities will *beat* the way `lowest` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pass a lambda to min to get the key/value directly.

```
while True:
    user = input("Enter city followed by temperature: ")
    if user == "stop":
        break
    name, temperature = user.split()
    city[name] = float(temperature)    # convert to float (or perhaps int)

lowest_city, lowest_temp = min(city.iteritems(), key=lambda x:x[1])
print("The coldest city is, %s, temperature = %.3f" % (lowest_city, lowest_temp))
```

Here the lambda function is telling the min function to select according to 
the second value of the tuple returned by the iteritems function.